# getting time format difference of two times

Tags: sql, firebird, datediff

I am trying to get the time format difference of two different times in firebird sql. I tried subtracting the two times but the result is not in time format.

```
  TIME_IN TIME,
  TIME_OUT TIME,
  DIFFERENCE TIME
SELECT 
  TIME_IN,
  TIME_OUT,
  TIME_OUT - TIME_IN

 Sample Data 
  TIME_IN = 7:00
  TIME_OUT = 12:00
  12:00 - 7:00
my expected output is 5:00
```

also tried using DATEDIFF but my result is not in time format

```
DATEDIFF (HOUR, TIME_IN, TIME_OUT)
```

Comment: What about your call to `DATEDIFF` is not working as you expect?

Comment: DATEDIFF result is not supposed to be time format, that would be weird. In your case, number of hours is the format, as it should be.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen yes... base on the code posted, only the hour difference is displayed, but my desired output is a tiime format

Comment: @SQL_M that is why I am asking sir/mam of different way in solving the problem.

Comment: From where I stand, you have already solved it with your DATEDIFF query, you just haven't realised.

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add some [sample data](http://plaintexttools.github.io/plain-text-table/) and the expected output based on that data. [Formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). ([edit] your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name edited

Answer (score 0):

The result of [`DATEDIFF`](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref25/firebird-25-language-reference.html#fblangref25-functions-scalarfuncs-datediff) is an integral value for the specified type. So the result of `DATEDIFF(HOUR, '07:00', '12:00')` is 5, and not 5:00.

The SQL `TIME` datatype is only for a 24 hour time within a day, it is not for measuring duration.

If for some reason you want to format it as a time, you will need to do that yourself. For example, by taking the difference in minutes, and then calculating the correct representation in hours and minutes.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
SELECT
   CAST(DATEDIFF(HOUR, CAST(EXTRACT(HOUR FROM CAST(CAST(:TIME_IN as varchar(5)) as time)) || ':00' as TIME), CAST(EXTRACT(HOUR FROM CAST(CAST(:TIME_OUT as varchar(5)) as time)) || ':00' as TIME))
        || ':' ||
        DATEDIFF(MINUTE, CAST('00:' || EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM CAST(CAST(:TIME_IN as varchar(5))as time)) as TIME), CAST('00:' || EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM CAST(CAST(:TIME_OUT as varchar(5)) as time)) as TIME)) as TIME)
FROM sth
```